# Upgrade PHP in Cent OS

Tags: php, joomla, centos

For some reason, I have to upgrade PHP version from 5.3.3 to 5.3.10 in order to let Joomla to run. But I googled for hours. All sources pointed to adding new repositories and typing some commands to upgrade. But in the end I can't upgrade the php from these repositories, not even to this specific version 5.3.10.

My production environment is running on 5.3.10. So it is better for me to upgrade to 5.3.10 as well. Is it because the version is too old that it cannot be installed from now?

I tried to download PHP from php.net and installed one. But I guess the httpd cannot recognize such PHP installations so that even I installed a newer version of PHP, my website still crash.

I would really appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: which repo did you try and fetch php from?

Comment: If you are using WHM then you can do this using EasyApache with a few clicks - you don't have to worry about doing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem before.

1. Remove php* installed by yum before

   ```
   yum remove php php-common php-cli
   ```
2. Download PHP 5.3.10. Unzip & switch into its directory
3. Install library required
   (Referring : http://open.litespeedtech.com/mediawiki/index.php/Help:Building_PHP_for_Joomla)

   ```
   yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-server libxml2-devel gd-devel gcc gcc-c++ make patch
   yum install httpd-devel libpng-devel #for apxs2; added for missing png headers
   ```
4. Configure the build files with extension which Joomla would use

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/opt/php5.3.10 --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-zlib --with-gd --enable-shmop --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-mbstring --with-iconv --with-libdir=lib64 --with-config-file-path=/etc/php.ini --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d

   make install
   ```

   I use `--with-libdir=lib64` because I find libmysqlclient.so in /usr/lib64

   and `--prefix, --with-config-file-path, --with-config-file-scan-dir` are optional
5. According to the warning during `make install` (please find your version at the end of it)

   ```
   libtool --finish /home/myuser/php-5.3.10/libs
   ```
6. Copy the config file to where it should be

   ```
   cp php.ini-production /etc/php.ini
   ```
7. Add the index.php in httpd.conf Directory Index

   ```
   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html.var
   ```
8. Restart httpd and it should be able to process php files